# Leaflet extension and Geosearch Directory not found

Tags: yii2, leaflet

Im relatively new to the Yii framework. I'm trying to get leaflet extension to work on my project. I installed it via composer and everything seems to be installed properly but when I try to insert it into an activeForm it throws me this error:

```
The file or directory to be published does not exist: /vendor/bower/leaflet/dist
```

Im trying to build a Geosearch field with a map. 
The extensions I have installed are:

"2amigos/yii2-leaflet-extension": "~1.0",
"2amigos/yii2-leaflet-geocoder-plugin": "~1.0",
"2amigos/yii2-leaflet-geosearch-plugin": "~1.0"

This is my code on the ActiveForm (its just the same as the provided on GitHub):

```
use dosamigos\leaflet\layers\TileLayer; 
use dosamigos\leaflet\LeafLet; 
use dosamigos\leaflet\types\LatLng; 
use dosamigos\leaflet\plugins\geosearch\GeoSearch; 
use dosamigos\leaflet\widgets\Map; 

<?php
    $center = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.67442740076734, 'lng' => 2.9347229003906246]); 

    $geoSearchPlugin = new GeoSearch([ 
        'service' => GeoSearch::SERVICE_OPENSTREETMAP 
    ]); 

    $tileLayer = new TileLayer([ 
        'urlTemplate' => 'link not allowed because its one of my first posts...', 
        'clientOptions' => [ 
            'attribution' => 'Tiles Courtesy of MapQuest ' . ', ' . 'Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ' . 'CC-BY-SA', 'subdomains' => '1234' 
        ] 
    ]); 

    $leafLet = new LeafLet([ 
        'name' => 'geoMap', 
        'tileLayer' => $tileLayer, 
        'center' => $center, 
        'zoom' => 10, 
        'clientEvents' => [ // setting up one of the geo search events for fun 
            'geosearch_showlocation' => 'function(e){ console.log(e.target); }' 
        ] 
    ]); 

    // add the plugin 
    $leafLet->installPlugin($geoSearchPlugin); 
    // run the widget (you can also use Map::widget([...])) 
    echo $leafLet->widget(); 
?>
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the original Leaflet js and css files are no longer available through Bower, and 2amigos have not changed their composer file to reflect the changes. Yii is attempting to publish a css file from the requested location, and the file doesn't yet exist, hence the error message. You'll either need to go to the [original Leaflet repository](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet) and copy the relevant files into the required directories, or update the composer file to point to the original files on GitHub. Sorry, I don't know enough about composer to be able to help with this bit!